# Merging polygons in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, merge, dissolve

I have 300 polygons in a single shapefile, I want merge some polygons together, when I merge two polygons the attribute does not come total count of two polygons,

What I need is, when I merge two polygon the attribute value has to add together and the total value has to come in merged polygon attribute.

Comment: Could you please reword this question.  Are you talking about creating single part features or dissolving boundaries?

Comment: What do you mean by "total value"?

Comment: If I understood you well,you wish to merge the polygons by selecting them in Edit mode and then merge them. Am I correct?

Comment: Alexandre Neto is right, when i Merge two polygon in Edit mode, the polygons are merging but the attribute does not calculate.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [dissolve tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000005n000000) in the toolbox: Datamanagement > Generalisation .

You can dissolve 2 fields with a common value with variable: dissolve_field

You can set the field you want to summerize in the variable: statistics_fields